# Configuring Servers farm (DNS + Active Directory)

Tags: configuration, windows-server-2008, dns

I have my DNS and active directory configured in Server1 (192.163.0.8).

FQDN: abc.domain.com
NetBIOS: abcde

My second Server has Sql Server Installed (both servers are using windows server 2008, but when I try to add Server2(192.163.0.9) to the domain I got the following error message:

an attempt to resolve the dns name of a dc in the domain being joined has failed.

running ipconfig /all in Server2 I got

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ipconfig /all

 Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Server2  
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :  
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid  
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No  
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No  

 Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :  
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter  
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 99-99-99-99-99-99  
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No  
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes  
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.163.0.9(Preferred)  
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0  
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.163.0.1  
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.8  
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

(MORE INFO)
In Server1:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ping server1

Pinging SERVER1.abc.domain.com [::1] from ::1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
.....


C:\Users\Administrator>ping abc.domain.com

Pinging abc.domain.com [192.163.0.8] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.163.0.8: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
....

C:\Users\Administrator>ping server1.abc.domain.com

Pinging SERVER1.abc.domain.com [::1] from ::1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
...

C:\Users\Administrator>ping server2

Pinging SERVER2 [192.163.0.9] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.163.0.9: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
.....
```

In Server2

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ping server2

Pinging SERVER2 [::1] from ::1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
.....

C:\Users\Administrator>ping server1

Pinging SERVER1 [192.163.0.8] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.163.0.8: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
.....

C:\Users\Administrator>ping abc.domain.com
Ping request could not find host abc.domain.com. Please check the name an
d try again.

C:\Users\Administrator>ping server1.abc.domain.com
Ping request could not find host server1.abc.domain.com. Please check the
name and try again.
```

Help please! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/12d31d89-4e4a-4451-bf10-cca38d32e84f

Answer (score 0):

Open Registry Editor (regedit).
 2. Navigate to the following registry key:
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\tcpip6\Parameters\
 Create the following registry value (DWORD type): DisabledComponents
 Set value to 0
 Restart your server.

Diwakar